# alert box with javascript in zend framework 2 action

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework2

I have a deleteAction() to delete categories in my project. But it is only possible to delete categories, when there are no untercategories and products in the category. This works all. My question is how to make an alert box in the deleteAction() of the IndexController.php?

Here in this view I call the action:

```
...

<a href="<?php echo $this->url('application/default', array('action'=>'delete','id' => $child->getId()));?>">L&oumlschen</a>

...
```

Here is my deleteAction():

```
 public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        if (!$id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
        }


        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $category = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Category')->find($id);
        $parentId = $category->getParent()[0]->getId();

        if(count($category->getCategoryId()) == 0 && count($category->getProductId()) == 0)
        {
            $em->remove($category);
            $em->flush();
        }
        else 
        {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("You can't delete this category!")';
            echo '</script>';
            //die();
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application/default',array('action'=>'details','id'=> $parentId));
    }
```

The alert box works, because when the `die();` is in the code I can se the alert box. Without the `die();` the action slurs the alert box.

Does someone now how to make the box visible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're approaching your feature horribly wrong.

Your `deleteAction()` should first know about both types of requests, the ones coming from a normal person who doesn't have JavaScript enabled and those from persons who have JS enabled and therefore do the "AJAX Request". For this you can use ZF2s `ControllerPlugin` which is called [`acceptableViewModelSelector()`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-acceptableviewmodelselector).

Your Controller then does different things depending on which context (normal/ajax request) you're in.

If it's a normal request:

- do all the checks
- if they are successful delete the entry and redirect the user to an overview page
- possibly add a success message using the [`flashMessenger()`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-flashmessenger)-Plugin

If it's an "AJAX Request":

- do all the checks as normal
- if they are successful delete the entry **and return a `JsonModel` that simply returns `success:true`**
- if they are not successful **return a `JsonModel` that simply returns `success:false`**
- in addition on `false` you should also return something like `message:'not possible because.....'`

Inside your view then you just render a normal Link as you know it and do your ajax request as you're doing right now. Depending on what the Return-Value of the request is, you know if it succeeded or not. If not you can throw an alertbox from your JS inside the view(!) stating the reason why things didn't work.